# Creating a Sudoku solver and board won't properly print

Tags: python

I've been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqUwSA0xI-s) sudoku board solver tutorial in python and everything has gone perfect until I call the `print_board` function. My code matches the tutorial exactly but still won't print a full board. I'm using pycharm with python 3.8 for reference and my code is below.

```py
def print_board(bo):
    for i in range(len(bo)):
        if i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
            print("- - - - - - - - - - - - - -")

    for j in range(len(bo[0])):
        if j % 3 == 0 and j != 0:
            print(" | ", end="")

        if j == 8:
            print(bo[i][j])
        else:
            print(str(bo[i][j]) + " ", end="")

print_board(board)
```

Output:

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
0 4 9  | 2 0 6  | 0 0 7
```

As you can see, only the last row of the last third section is printing

Comment: Can you check the indentation in the question please? I assume the two for loops are actually part of the function, or at least meant to be? (In case you didn't know Python uses indentation depth to define scopes.)

Comment: And can you at least tell us the time stamp in the video where this code is shown? Can you try copying and pasting the code from the accompanying page: https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/python-programming/sudoku-solver-backtracking/

Comment: Checking the original code on techwithtim.net, it looks like you haven't nested the `for j` loop inside the `for i` loop. `i` is the row you're printing and `j` the column, so you need to run the `for j` loop for every value of `i`, and as it is you're just running it for the last `i` only because you've got the indentation wrong.